# What is this code trying to do?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, macros, inline-assembly

I'm trying to understand how the following code is working:

```
#define M32toX128(x128,m32) __asm__               \
  ("movddup %1, %0\n\t"                           \
   "movsldup    %0, %0"                           \
   : "=&x"(x128) : "m"(m32) )
```

I have only basic assembly knowledge. Searching around and from the context of the program that is using it, I have understood that it is duplicating a 32-bit variable and storing the result in a 128-bit variable.
My questions are:

- What do `%0` and `%1` refer to?
- What are the colons (`:`) doing?
- What is the actual assembly code that is executed? I mean after replacing `%n`s, `"=&x"(x128)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc inline assembly is a complicated beast, too complicated to describe here in detail.
As a quick overview, the general form of the asm block is: `"template" : outputs : inputs : clobbers`. You can refer to the outputs and inputs (collectively known as operands) in the template by using `%` followed by a zero-based index. Thus `%0` refers to `x128` and `%1` refers to `m32`. For each operand, you can specify a constraint that tells the compiler how to allocate said operand. The `=&x` means, allocate the `x128` as an early-clobber output in any available xmm register, and the `m` means use a memory address for the operand. See the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for the mind-boggling details.

The actual assembly generated will depend on the operand choices the compiler uses. You can see that if you ask for an assembly listing using the `-S` option. Assuming `m32` is a local variable, the code may look like:

```
movddup x(%esp), %xmmN
movsldup %xmmN, %xmmN
```

Note that gcc inline assembler is of course gcc and architecture specific, and that means it's simpler to use the equivalent compiler intrinsics.

Answer (score 2):

This code will be passed from GCC to the assembler stage. Some part of the macro will be replaced in the process. Here is the documentation: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

`%0` and `%1` will be replaced with the values that you passed to the C macro.

The `:` is used to separate parts of the macro. The first mandatory part is the template. The second one is for output operands. See http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5 for the full.

In this case, you have an output `=` which is 128 bits (`x`) and which gets trashed (`&`) by the macro. `m` means this is a memory operand.